# Issue to access KSQL CLI on Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

I'm trying access the KSQL CLI for first time on Windows terminal but I got the error: `Unable to find image 'cp-ksql-cli:5.3.1' locally`

To do it I get docker images

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
cnfldemos/kafka-connect-datagen             0.1.3-5.3.1         f88aea51c605        2 weeks ago         1.03GB
confluentinc/ksql-examples                  5.3.1               b9fb66d15198        4 weeks ago         499MB
confluentinc/cp-ksql-server                 5.3.1               7c40b5e474a2        4 weeks ago         522MB
confluentinc/cp-ksql-cli                    5.3.1               a488fb1cc028        4 weeks ago         510MB
confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka            5.3.1               2b5ee743a097        4 weeks ago         646MB
confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center   5.3.1               c29150c8588e        4 weeks ago         771MB
confluentinc/cp-schema-registry             5.3.1               b7abcb36a4d9        4 weeks ago         986MB
confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest                  5.3.1               27066ec8dcc2        4 weeks ago         984MB
confluentinc/cp-zookeeper                   5.3.1               711eb38827f6        4 weeks ago         590MB
```

So:

```
$ docker run cp-ksql-cli:5.3.1 http://ksql-server:8088
```

also it:

```
$ docker run confluentinc/cp-ksql-cli:5.3.1 http://ksql-server:8088
```

and got the error:

```
Unable to find image 'cp-ksql-cli:5.3.1' locally
```

I'am a new on KSQL and I don't know if this is the correct way to access the CLI. On the google I found this [tutorial](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/tutorials/basics-docker.html#ksql-quickstart-docker) but I can't understanted how enter on the KSQL CLI terminal. Besides that I don't know how it connect with my Kafka broker, zookeper and others..

**SOLVED**

Accessed using: `$ docker-compose exec ksql-cli ksql http://ksql-server:8088`

Comment: Typo... `confluentic` --> **`confluentinc`**. Why aren't you using the commands in the tutorial, though?

Answer (score 3):

> I don't know how it connect with my Kafka broker, zookeper and others..

KSQL CLI doesn't. Kafka is connected to Zookeeper, and KSQL **server** is connected to Kafka.

KSQL CLI only connects to KSQL Server.

Therefore, you need a total of at least 4 containers to be running at once, which is why Docker Compose is recommended, as the tutorial you linked to shows.

> the correct way to access the CLI

It should be like this, where `some_network` is a Docker network that already hosts a `ksql-server` container

```
docker run --rm -ti --network=some_network confluentinc/cp-ksql-cli:5.3.1 http://ksql-server:8088
```

(or longer version shown in the tutorial is `docker run --network some_network --rm --interactive --tty ...`)

Comment: You is alright, but I got the error: `*************************************ERROR**************************************
Remote server at http://localhost:8088 does not appear to be a valid KSQL
server. Please ensure that the URL provided is for an active KSQL server.

The server responded with the following error:
Error issuing GET to KSQL server. path:/
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Caused by: Could not connect to the server.
********************************************************************************`

Comment: I was able to acces with: `docker-compose exec ksql-cli ksql http://ksql-server:8088`

Comment: You didn't specify docker compose was being used in the question, but glad to hear it

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you didn't open the 8088 port.
Checkout below docker commands.

1) KSQL server docker start

```
$ docker run \
    -p 127.0.0.1:8088:8088 \
    -e KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=localhost:9092 \
    -e KSQL_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8088/ \
    -e KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID=ksql_standalone_1_ \
    confluentinc/cp-ksql-server:5.3.1
```

2) KSQL-cli docker start

```
$ docker run --net=host --interactive --tty \
    confluentinc/cp-ksql-cli:5.3.1 \
    http://localhost:8088
```

If you do this, it will work out.
Good luck.